# How to limit access for a user to particular pages in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How can access for an external user to data collected by Google Analytics (GA) in combination with Google Tag Manager (GTM) be restricted, to particular pages based tags within specified HTML tags in a page?

E.g. I want to grant a specific GA-user access to data collected only on my pages where this tag exists and the content matches "example".

```
<li class="base-info--entry entry--supplier">
    <span class="entry--label">Supplier:</span>
    <span class="entry--content" itemprop="brand">Example</span>
</li>
```

Now the only approach I found is using GTM. My approach would be to insert a second GA tracking code of a restricted property to that user. However in that case there would be two GA codes on this page. One I inserted based on the trigger and the other which is on all pages.

Is there a better approach than this?

I inserted a variable that matches the css selector

```
$(".info_box_sqm .info_box_rght").text()
```

[image]

With the trigger on the ID via regex:
00956896|'00956896'|'00956900'

[image]

But it does not fire:
[image]

The value is "null" while looking at the console of dev tools the selector returns the ID.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution you have with double tracking is really what people seem to do. And it does look like a good practice to follow. You may spice it up with automated generation of tracking on-demand via GTM API if you need it.

There are caveats though. That new internal property will miss some things. Things like original attribution. Other session-related things may be cut off. Things like the original referrer (which is essentially the same). Landing pages will be those where the new session started rather than original, real landing pages. The new property will assume there are no other pages other than what it sees in the immediate document.referrer

Besides the caveats, additional parallel tracking doesn't really break anything. Even multiple GTM containers on one page coexist adequately, as one would expect. The multiple GTM containers approach is often used on white label services.

Another approach would be way more awkward. It would involve taking the data from GA programmatically and only sharing a hardcoded part of it. It could likely be done through BQ-only, so just SQL. It's a solution, but double tracking is way more elegant solution here if the clients don't like looking at raw data using SQL.

Comment: I just tried to generate a new GA property for this use but Analytics only gives me a google tag under data streams within this property not a UA tracking code. Either I do not know where to find the UA code or there is something else wrong. Any idea?

Comment: You do know that UA is being deprecated in a few months? Maybe your main concern should be moving your set up to GA4 instead of launching new UA implementations? [Here](https://faq.businesstech.fr/en/faq/470-how-to-add-a-ua-property-to-my-existing-ga4-property), this is how you link your existing UA property to GA4.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I got it configured. However somehow the trigger does not fire, despite the regex and CSS selector beeing OK. This seems to be difficult to debug. The CSS selector works as chrome dev tools returns the ID in console when using it. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: add the screenshots of your set up as well as debugging screenshots from the GTM preview.

Comment: I added the example to the question

Comment: And this error is somehow related to the new property that you've added? How did you add it? You're supposed to use the same trigger for the pageview as the old property uses.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to trigger the pv based on the selector. No, looks like what you're trying to select is not there on pagload. You will likely have to move the pageview to later, when the DOM element is there. Or use a different selector. It's easier to do it based on url rather than dom elements.

Comment: I might understand the concept wrong. I added a new GA4 prroperty in GA and the new tag from the property to GTM where I added the the trigger and the variable to it. I also tried to do "Dom Ready", but without success.

Comment: well you have to measure when the element you rely on gets shown. One way to do it is insert a breakpoint, another is to make a CJS variable that would check if it's there and return an answer. You'd see the answer in debugger when inspecting events and corresponding variables.

Comment: I found the problem. The css needs to look different then in Google Console as the interpreter is different,. The solution is e.g.: meta[itemprop=”product:brand”]